# Gitlab CI: depend on all the jobs that extend certain configuration

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need to depend on many jobs that do similar things and extend from a single configuration. Right now I list them all manually, but is there a way to do it automatically?

```yaml
.job-template:
  artifacts:
    # some artifacts
job1:
  extends: .job-template

job2:
  extends: .job-template

final_job:
  script:
    # work with all the artifacts from previous jobs
  dependencies:
    # everything that extends from .job-template
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try grouping those jobs in a stage and use this stage as requirement for final job ?

Comment: They are in a "build" stage, but they are not the only ones in that stage. I'd rather not to introduce a separate stage just to ease the dependencies. Also, you should put such questions in comments, not in answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I list them all manually, but is there a way to do it automatically?

That's pretty much what you have to do. There is no automatic way to declare `dependencies:` and there is no way to declare a dependency from the dependent job(s).

You can implicitly do this by ordering of `stages:` and the `stage:` for the respective jobs and omitting `dependencies:` (by default, jobs depend on all other jobs in previous stages).

Comment: >(by default, jobs depend on all other jobs in previous stages)

Does it mean that all the artifacts from all the jobs are downloaded automatically?

Comment: yes @Morse that is correct